# angular class and ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So in Angular you can do this:

```
 ng-class="{ 'my-class': widget.widgetId == '1'}
```

Which will give the element the class of my-class if the widget.widgetId equals 1.

You can also do this:

```
 class="col-md-{{widget.size}}"
```

Which will give the element a class of col-md- and then returns whatever widget.size is set to.

However what if I want to do what I'm doing in the second example but with ng-class. For example the following:

```
ng-class="{ 'col-md-{{widget.size}}': widget.widgetId == '1'}"
```

I've tried the above with various syntax but it does not seem to work. Is this possible with ng-class?

Comment: In (angular v.1.1.4+) they introduced support for ternary operator, maybe it could be useful.

Comment: can you give fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of using ng-class:

HTML:

```
<button ng-class="getLanguageOptionClass(lan)" ng-repeat="lan in language.available" ng-click="language.current=lan">{{lan}}</button>
```

Javascript

```
var I18nController = function($scope){
     $scope.language = {
         current: 'no', 
         available: ['en', 'no', 'sv', 'da', 'fi']
     };
    $scope.getLanguageOptionClass = function(language){
        return ($scope.language.current==language) ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-info';
    }
};
```

Description : `getLanguageOptionClass` gets called with `lan` as a parameter, which returns a value which is assigned as a class.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/j4u2L/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure wether above will work or not but you can achieve this using by defining a function inside your controller as,

```
$scope.getClass= function(widget){
    var baseClass = "col-md-";
    if(widget.widgetId==='1'){
         return baseClass + widget.size;
    }
}
```

Inside your html use it like,

```
ng-class="getClass(widget)"
```

Answer (score 0):

define a function in controller to get class name processed

```
$scope.getClassName = function(widgetSize){
  return 'col-md-' + widgetSize;
}
```

call this function from ng-class

```
ng-class="getClassName(widget.size)"
```